# Changing background color on scrolling at a certain position

Tags: jquery, css

i was working on this and what i am doing is i am changing background color on certain position on scrolling.
Now it's working fine till red color but then again the green color is not showing up.
here is the code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

            if (scroll_pos < 210) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'black');
            }
            else if (scroll_pos > 210) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'red');
            }
            else if (scroll_pos > 410) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'orange');

            }

            else if (scroll_pos > 710) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'green');

            }

        });
    });
```

And here is the Fiddle
[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/x69xm/)

Please tell me if i am doing something wrong with if else.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var scroll_pos = 0;
            $(document).scroll(function () {
                scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

                if (scroll_pos < 210) {
                    $("body").css('background-color', 'black');
                }
                else if (scroll_pos > 210 && scroll_pos < 410) {
                    $("body").css('background-color', 'red');
                }
                else if (scroll_pos > 410 && scroll_pos < 710) {
                    $("body").css('background-color', 'orange');

                }

                else if (scroll_pos > 710) {
                    $("body").css('background-color', 'green');

                }
                console.log(scroll_pos)

            });
        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x69xm/3/)

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x69xm/2/)

You need to add additional conditions to the `if` statements to limit the `background-color` to the `scroll_pos`.

```
            if (scroll_pos < 210) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'black');
            }
            else if (scroll_pos > 210 && scroll_pos < 410) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'red');
            }
            else if (scroll_pos > 410 && scroll_pos < 710) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'orange');
            }
            else if (scroll_pos > 710) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'green');

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var scroll_pos = 0;
        var color = 'black';
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

            if (scroll_pos < 210) {
                color = 'black';
            }
            if (scroll_pos > 210) {
                color = 'red';
            }
            if (scroll_pos > 410) {
                color = 'orange';
            }
            if (scroll_pos > 710) {
                color = 'green';
            }
            $("body").css('background-color', color );

        });
    });
```

Store the color to use in the variable. Change the variable as the condition gets larger. Apply the variable as background-color property at the end. No need to compare if greater and smaller, just build greater in the order of comparison.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/x69xm/4/